# AFNetworking 2.0 Supports Background task for iOS 6 and iOS 7 Both?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking

Please give your idea on background task related to upload a file using AFNetworking Library in Background , which will work in both iOS6 and IOS7.

I have search on google , But in mostly case Background task will be done by using afnetworking for iOS7 , NO One implement it for iOS6.
1.http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial
2.http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial

NsurlSession can be used for IOS7 But How to manage uploading with iOS6
Please help me .Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Background fetch is not supported in iOS 6. It was first introduced in iOS 7, along with NSURLSession et al, hence the update to AFNetworking 2.0. Nobody has implemented this for iOS 6 because it is not supported by the operating system.

Comment: Thanks for comment , So there is another way to upload file in background in ios 6

Comment: No, it's not supported by the operating system.